# Javascript causes slow asp.net 4 site on ipad 3

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, ipad

i am trying to develop a web application using a master page on asp.net 4. the application needs to work on an ipad.

i had the site already built, but it loaded so slowly that it timed-out, so i decided to rebuild from scratch to see what might be causing the issue. i put in the least amount of html possible to test, and it loaded in under a second. however, as soon as i added

`<script type="text/javascript">
</script>`

within the master page head tag the site took close to 10 seconds to load. the same problem occurs if i add a .net control to the content page.

i am using an ipad 3 with javascript turned on.

does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC or WebForms? WebForms will add a lot of unnecessary markup to your pages, which may slow them down.

Comment: sorry, i should have indicated that in the original posting - the site was developed using webForms.

Comment: Are you using any third-party controls such as Telerik or DevExpress?

Comment: no, and right now the site is bare-bones - just some html markup in addition to the content placeholders.

Comment: How is the behavior of the pages in a browser ( say chrome ,not in ipad ) ?

Comment: i tried it in chrome 17 and there was no delay.

Comment: Were you able to figure out the issue ? I am curious to know what is making the page slow in ipad.

Comment: sorry, no, i abandoned webForms and instead attempted to employ mvc. unfortunately, the client was bought out and the buyers cancelled the project, so i have therefore stopped development. i would, however, like to revisit the project at some point to see how mvc works with ipads.

Comment: I have the same problem, asked a different question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26933772/mvc-4-website-very-slow-on-ipad but no helpful answers!